# How to plot a bar plot with matplotlib using two single values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a bar plot with two values for two classes **A** and **B**  using matplotlib.
My values are `a = 43` and `b = 21`.

I need the plot to look like this:

[image]

I have been trying to do it almost an hour using matplotlib examples but eventually gave up. Maybe somebody can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`bar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
s = fig.add_subplot(111)
s.bar([1, 2], [43, 21], width=1)
s.set_xlim(0.5, 3.5)
fig.savefig('t.png')
```

[image]

*Edit:* following the specs more accurately.

Comment: Minor detail, but I believe OP needs `width=1.0`:)

Comment: Yes, I guess. I didn't like how it looked, but for the sake of accuracy I'll fix it.

Comment: Compromise with `color='w',edgecolor='k',lw=5`?:)

Comment: And `xkcd` style too, probably. Left as an exercise for OP :)

Answer (score 3):

As of [mpl 1.5](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#plot-bar-and-barh-with-labels) you can simply do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax  = plt.subplots()
ax.bar([1, 2], [43, 21], width=1,
       tick_label=['A', 'B'], align='center')
```

[image]

Comment: out of interest, which part is new in 1.5? `tick_label`?

Comment: Yes, added link to whats new page to answer.

Answer (score 1):

A few variations on fjarri's answer,

- make it easier to change the number of bars and their values
- label each bar

like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

BAR_WIDTH = 1.     # 0. < BAR_WIDTH <= 1.

def main():
    # the data you want to plot
    categories = ["A", "B"]
    values     = [ 43,  21]
    # x-values for the center of each bar
    xs = np.arange(1, len(categories) + 1)
    # plot each bar centered
    plt.bar(xs - BAR_WIDTH/2, values, width=BAR_WIDTH)
    # add bar labels
    plt.xticks(xs, categories)
    # make sure the chart is centered
    plt.xlim(0, len(categories) + 1)
    # show the results
    plt.show()

main()
```

which produces

[image]